# Controller's variable value isn't updated in Angularjs material Toast template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to use the '**toast**' component of [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast) inside a simple Angularjs app.

The documentation is very vague and doesn't even follow its own rules (for example, the necessary use of 'md-actions' class for action buttons). Anyhow, the problem is as follows:

I have created a 'Preset' for my toast with the following config:

```
$mdToastProvider.addPreset('docEditPreset', {
            options: function () {
                return {
                    templateUrl: 'App/Components/Document_Edit/DocumentEditToast.html',
                    hideDelay: 1200,
                    position: 'bottom right',
                    toastClass: 'document-edit-toast',
                    controller: 'DocumentEditController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                };
            }
        });
```

And the template for toast is:

```
<md-toast>

    <span class="md-toast-text">{{ vm.toastText }}</span>

</md-toast>
```

As it is shown in the code above, I have a variable named `vm.toastText` inside the template's `<span>` tag which resides in `DocumentEditController` and is *supposed* to be visible in the toast.

The code for `DocumentEditController`:

```
vm.toastText = '';

function showToast() {
            vm.toastText = 'I AM A TOAST!';
            $mdToast.show(
                $mdToast.docEditPreset()
            );
        }
```

(I should mention that `vm` is the `$scope` of the controller. The toast config has also been named the same for consistency.)

So the idea is to change the value of `vm.toastText` **before** running the toast function. I was hoping to get the updated value inside my toast's template. At the moment, the toast seems to only show the initial value of `vm.toastText` which is an empty string.

How can I update the value of my variable inside the `DocumentEditController` and use it in the toast template?

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/DreamWalker/pen/aYgazy)** on CodePen

Comment: Probably creating a new controller instance each time you call `$mdToast.show()`. Can use `textContent(string)` method of `$mdToast` service

Comment: Create a runnable demo in plunker (or other sandbox) that shows how you are working with toast

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comment. I will try to use new controller instances to see what happens. here's the Demo to make things a bit clearer: https://codepen.io/DreamWalker/pen/aYgazy

Comment: Correct. Without using a service

Comment: Uh, I see. So it kind of creates a copy of "TestController" with the initial values? if so, will I ever be able to link the values from the original controller to the duplicate?

Comment: No...neither instance knows about the other. It is like calling the same function twice....they are not connected to each other

Comment: So the final solution is that I have no solutions at all? I should try to change the structure and/or use the 'new instance each time' method, right?

Comment: Why can't you use the `$mdToast` method `textString()`? Look at source in demo to see it used https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast

Comment: In my case, `textContent()` will always be a static string. I am trying to call the `show()` function once and change the message of the toast based on the situation. Correct me if I'm wrong, but using `textContent()` would be like pre-filling the `vm.toastText` variable with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is stuck at managing a problem like this, I found a workaround.

Instead of using my main controller (`DocumentEditController` in my question), I created a new controller, for example `ToastController`, and then used `locals` to pass in the variables I needed.

So the function in `DocumentEditController` became:

```
function showToast(message) {
            $mdToast.show({
                templateUrl: 'App/Components/Shared/Toast/ToastTemplate.html',
                hideDelay: 1200,
                position: 'bottom right',
                controller: 'ToastController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                locals: {
                    message: message
                }
            });
        }
```

and `ToastController`:

```
function ToastController($scope, $mdToast, message) {

        var vm = this;

        //=== Variables ===//
        vm.message = message;

        //=== Function declarations ===//
        vm.closeToast = closeToast;

        //=== Function implementations ===//

        function closeToast() {
            $mdToast.hide();
        }

    }

ToastController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdToast', 'message'];
```

HTML template:

```
<md-toast>

    <span class="md-toast-text">{{ vm.message }}</span>

    <md-button ng-click="vm.closeToast()" class="md-action md-icon-button">
        <md-icon class="md-light">close</md-icon>
    </md-button>

</md-toast>
```

I completely removed the Preset I was trying to create in my app's config and instead declared the toast in my main controller (`DocumentEditController`).

Now inside my main controller, I can simply call the `showToast(message)` function with the desired message - be it a string or a variable containing a string.